# Showing that a family of functions is not normal.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F$ be the set analytic functions in $B(0,1)$ satisfying $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$. Prove $F$ is not normal.

I've been trying to come up with a counter example, but I am failing. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can show this?

The family of functions F is said to be normal in a subset of $S\subset \mathbb{C}$ if every subsequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions $f_n\in F$ contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on every compact subset of S.

Comment: Could you please define normal? .... it comes up a lot in mathematics.

Comment: What is your dot product? Does $f\cdot g =\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n (z)=z+nz^{2}$. Then $f_n (0)=0$, $f_n'(0)=1$ but no subsequence converges uniformly on compact subsets. For example, $[0,1/2]$ is a compact subset on which the sequence is unbounded.